# my function does not execute by the router

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a router and it should execute my function when the user wants to access /matches URL, but it doesn't
this is my controller that my function is wroten in there

```
const matchModel = require(`./../models/matchModel`);
//This function will get  matches
exports.getMatches = async (req, res) => {
   const matches = await matchModel.find();
   res.status(200).json({
     status: "success",
     results: matches.length,
     data: {
       matches,
     },
   });
};
```

this is my route handler that should execute the function in the controller

```
const express = require("express");
const matchController = require(`./../controllers/matchController`);
const router = express.Router();

router.route("/matches").get(matchController.getMatches);

module.exports = router;
```

and this is my app file that adds URLs to middleware

```
const express = require("express");
const matchRouter = require(`./routes/matchRoutes`);
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
//importing routers
app.use("/matches", matchRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

and after all, I run this server.js file to run my app

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
//setting up dotenv setting and
dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
const conString = process.env.DATABASE_CON_STRING;
const port = process.env.PORT;

const app = require(`./app`);

mongoose
  .connect(conString, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connection to DB has been established successfully!");
  });

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server is running...");
});
```

Comment: you are using `/matches` 2 times, one when defining the router and one when assigning it to the app, check if hitting `/matches/matches` hits your endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading the router under `/matches`
`app.use("/matches", matchRouter);`

Then you are loading the `/matches` route under that router
`router.route("/matches").get(matchController.getMatches);`

That is going to make the route `/matches/matches`.

You probably want it to be `router.route('')`. This will be the index route under the `/matches` router.

Comment: oh my god, what a dummy mistake, thanks for your help, you saved my day❤